# iPhone 4s headphone jack stops and starts working randomly

Tags: iphone, ios, headphones

iPhone 4s headphone jack will stop working at times and I have to believe this is some sort of software or internal error. Reason being is it will start working again after a while. I've done a hard reset and checked all the settings.

Comment: Please don’t include two questions in one question. To answer your second question, see [How to reinstall old iOS software?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304038/37797).

Comment: Physically, there may be cruft (dust, crumbs, etc) inside the headphone socket that needs cleaning out. Some compressed air in a can may help dislodge it. As for a software/internal error - that's impossible to diagnose without having the device on the test bench.

Comment: To answer your second (now deleted) question, older versions of iTunes stored iOS apps (.ipa files) at this path: `/Users/your_user_name/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications`. The apps should still be there even if you upgraded the iTunes app. The biggest problem is loading an older version of iTunes that uses these iOS .ipa files to reload your 4S.

Comment: I believe it may have been an app. I was getting ready to go for a run and starting a running app and then I saw a volume icon or symbol with a line across  it as a new pop-up right after starting the app. I deleted the app but it didn't get my earphone jack back.

Comment: There might also be a loose connection if you have e.g. dropped it with the head phone plug in at a time.